# How to prove the surjective function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Define $h: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ by:$$h(z)=\operatorname{Re}(z)+\operatorname{Im}(z)$$
d define $f$ by the formula $f(z)=\log (h(z))$

*(a)* Prove that $h$ is surjective. Easy!

*(b)* Find the implied domain of $f$ and sketch it in a complex plane diagram.

*(c)* Find the implied range of $f$

Help me with this;(

I have no idea how to prove it.
When I put complex equation in $Im(z)$ part, they make output of some number with $i$.
So I was thinking the codomain is not $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I don't quite understand why this question was downvoted. Nonetheless, Ariel, you should try to use better wording while asking the question. It'll allow us to help you. I've written up an answer for you. If you do not understand it, please let me know.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats I suspect that it was downvoted because this question reads like a homework problem which the asker has asked the MSE community to complete for them.  Such a question is not a good fit for MSE---there is no specific mathematical issue being highlighted, and MSE is not a homework mill.

Comment: Ahhh, alright, fair enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a complex function is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3647473/prove-that-a-complex-function-is-surjective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have your function $h:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$h(z) = \Re(z) + \Im(z)$$

To prove surjectivity, all you need to do is prove that for every real number, there exists a complex number $z$ such that the sum of its real & imaginary parts yields that real number.

So, let $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, define $z = r + i0$. So, clearly:

$$h(z) = h(r+i0) = \Re(z)+\Im(z) = r + 0 = r$$

Since that gives us the correct result and $r$ was arbitrarily chosen, it follows that $h(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{R}$. That proves surjectivity.

Let me also say something about the injectivity of this function. So, clearly, this function is not injective. Why?

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, notice that $z_1 = \frac{r}{2} +i\cdot \frac{r}{2}$ and $z_2 = r + i0$ yield exactly the same result when used as inputs for the function? So, clearly, the preimages are not unique and, therefore, this function is not injective.

This is just a bit of extra work on my part but, hopefully, it should teach you something about how to approach such problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping !!

Comment: I was so suffering with it . I was so annoyed with the imaginary number part!

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm going to add a few more details to my answer and hopefully, you'll benefit more from those. If you do like it, then please accept it :D

Comment: How do I accept it? Pushing the button with the shape of check?

Comment: That's exactly right :D

Comment: Could you tell me how to solve b and c too? I just can get it :(

Comment: But I totally understand your solutions!

Comment: I think you should post b) and c) as separate questions, linking that question back to this one with my answer. Answering all three at once would make it a little packed.

Comment: You mean I need to post new 2 questions? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Nope, just post one question with parts b) and c), since both of them are closely related to each other. Then, link this question there so that someone else answering you will have access to this discussion.